# Why is my excel file size jumping to 0 Kb's when being updated by Panda's?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm using Python (3.7) and Panda's to do web searches for company data and then write each result to an output .xlsx file.  The output file is constantly being updated after each iteration. I'm doing this on a machine with 8 gigs of RAM.

However, I've noticed that when running larger data sets (+12k rows), that output file size goes from around 2000 Kb down to 0 Kb and then back to 2000 Kb when it moves to the next row.

The problem is if I stop the script (or there's a crash) when the output file happens to be at 0 Kb, the file gets corrupted and I lose everything.

I'm not sure what kind of solution to pursue here.   Is there a setting I should be making use of in the read_excel? Or perhaps something needs to be done on the to_excel?

I'm a novice here, learning as I go so any help would be appreciated.

Tks,
Rhelm

I've seen discussions regarding "pickling" and having panda's read the file in "chunks" . But its not clear if that would address my problem(s).

**UPDATE** I was mistaken in that this issue is limited to large file sizes.  The xlsx file size will jump to 0 Kb no matter the size.  It's just more noticeable when working with larger files.  My problem remains the same: If my script stops before the final write AND the stage of the output file was presently down to 0 Kb, I lose all previously written data.

Comment: I don't believe excel files can be read/written in chunks, because of the XLSX format. (There's no `chunksize` argument in read_excel for instance). You need to read and write the entire file every time (which is why it goes temporarily to 0, then back to the full size). Perhaps you are looking more for something like a `csv` where you can write in append mode. Or do all of your processing and then write only once at the end.

Comment: Thanks, ALollz.  So, basically, I would switch my setup to read/write csv's in an "append mode" and then run the final save as an xlsx?

Comment: How are you structuring your code? Perhaps massage the data within the iteration but don't write to file until everything is done, so you don't risk a corruption mid process?

Comment: Thanks, Krrr. I'm writing the result found to the file after each row gets searched so if I had to stop it, I wouldn't lose anything.  That approach worked fine as I frequently have to stop it. But now with larger files, that seems to be the problem.

Comment: It sounds like you should be writing each chunk to its own file and once you have processed the entire input file, decide how to merge the results. That will protect the program from trying to read or write a file that is too large.

Answer (score 1):

are you calling writer.save() at the end?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

if you don't call the last line, the file will jump to 0 and will be corrupt.